# Error in dbDriver("PostgreSQL") : could not find function "dbDriver"

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I have a shiny-server set up on an Amazon Web Services instance, I am trying to get my app.R onto it but am getting this error:

```
Error in dbDriver("PostgreSQL") : could not find function "dbDriver"
Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> get_query
Execution halted
```

I think it has to do with the library install of the package DBI, but I've tried installing it again on the instance and haven't been successful.
Not sure what to try next..

Here's the whole image of the error and I can add any other information required:

[image]

Also I can confirm that the shiny-server is installed correctly because this page loads normally:

[image]

This is how I've tried to install my packages in the instance:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages(c('shiny', 'shinythemes', 'shinycssloaders', 'dplyr', 'xlsx','ggplot2','ggthemes','DT','stringr','RPostgreSQL','tidyr','dbplyr', DBI','splitstackshape'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

and dbDriver is a function in the DBI package

This is part of what my app.R code contains:

```
required_packages <- c("shiny", "shinythemes", "shinycssloaders", "dplyr", "xlsx","ggplot2","ggthemes","DT","stringr","RPostgreSQL","tidyr","dbplyr","DBI","splitstackshape"
                       ,"magrittr","tidyverse","shinyjs","data.table","plotly")
absent_packages <- required_packages[!(required_packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(absent_packages)) install.packages(absent_packages)
set.seed(1)

get_query <- function(querystring){
  # create a connection

  # loads the PostgreSQL driver
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  # creates a connection to the postgres database
  # note that "con" will be used later in each connection to the database
  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "postgres",  host = "/var/run/postgresql", port = 5432, user = "postgres", password = "pw")
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
  #rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")

  query <- eval(parse(text = querystring))
  return(query)
}
```

And these are the tables and connection info to the postgreSQL database on the same instance:
[image]

If I add DBI:: in front of dbConnect() and dbDisconnect() and used RPostgres::Postgres() as the driver in the dbConnect function I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to make this reproducible because I think it has something to do with my instance setup specifically. Should I add the libraries I have installed?
I've set up a postgreSQL database and shiny-server on my instance so I'm hoping someone else has seen this error before and would know what it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing a package does not mean it is loaded into your namespace. Further, the use of `dbDriver` is deprecated, as shown in `?dbDriver`:

> These methods are deprecated, please consult the documentation of the individual backends for the construction of driver instances.

I suggest either explicitly loading `DBI` or using `DBI::` with each call to its functions (not a bad idea anyway):

```
library(DBI)
get_query <- function(querystring){
  # create a connection
  # save the password that we can "hide" it as best as we can by collapsing it

  # creates a connection to the postgres database
  # note that "con" will be used later in each connection to the database
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), dbname = "postgres",  host = "/var/run/postgresql", port = 5432, user = "postgres", password = "pw")
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con))
  #rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")

  query <- eval(parse(text = querystring))
  return(query)
}
```

(Again, you don't *need* to do both `library(DBI)` and use `DBI::`, you choose.)

I used `RPostgres::Postgres()` here, but this applies also to many other drivers, including `RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()`, `RSQLite::SQLite()`, and `rodbc::odbc()` (several others exist).

Further points, though I don't know what else you have going on here to be certain:

- making a connection each time you call this function can get "expensive"; consider connecting outside of this function and passing in your `con` object; if this is a one-or-two-times thing, then you might be alright as-is;
- the use of `eval(parse(...))` seems wrong ... executing user-provided queries is flat-out dangerous, look up "SQL Injection" if you are not familiar. Why not just `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, querystring)`?

Comment: I tried adding the DBI:: and using RPostgres::Postgres() as the driver and now I'm getting another error that looks a bit similar to the first one (added it to my question above). Those last points are good suggestions, I will look into them, thanks!

Comment: Don't use `dbDriver`. You don't need it. And it's deprecated: each backend driver *"should provide an exported object with the same name as the package"* (from `?dbDriver`). But if *insist*, try `DBI::dbDriver("Postgres")` (but really, don't).

Comment: oh sorry I meant dbConnect and dbDisconnect, I will fix it

Comment: Finally got it, I didn't have the library RPostgres installed... silly mistake!

Comment: There is also `RPostgreSQL`, same purpose, mostly the same, different authors and code-path.